# The java process that run hbase script was blocked and can not kill it

Tags: java, shell, hbase

I want to run a hbase script in java a program, the script is

```
balancer
exit
```

the java code is

```
<!-- language: java -->
public static void exec(String[] command) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        final Process process = builder.start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String line = null;
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                try {
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String line = null;
                BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                try {
                    while ((line = err.readLine()) != null) {
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        err.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    exec( new String[]{HBASE_HOME + "/bin/hbase", "shell", 
            "./balancer.sql"});
}
```

I use two threads to handle the errStream and inputStream to avoid deadlock, but
the process is still blocked and can not killed by command "kill -9". I run it in eclipse, the eclipse also be blocked.

Comment: debug by executing the script in shell and check your output.

Comment: I have run the script in shell and found it works,this problem  continues to perplex me.